# No subscriptions found in the old Azure portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am using a visualstudio account in Azure. i have created a new user and given admin access to the active directory to this user. I also added this user as the owner to the subscriptions i had.
I now login as this into the new portal. I can see the subscription that i have. However i do not see the icon for Azure ActiveDirectory. Therefore i try to login to the old portal. This time I get stopped by a "No subscriptions found" prompt which does not let me for farther.
What is going on? why is there such discrepency between the two sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic (i.e. old) site only works with the old access model (service admin and co-admin), and requires at least one subscription to get into the site. The new site uses the fine-grained RBAC model (owner, contributor, etc...), and does not require any subscription just to get in to the site.

Adding a user as an 'Owner' in the new Azure portal [does not make them a co-administrator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/#how-to-add-an-admin-for-a-subscription), and thus, does not give them access to the classic portal:

> The owners you added through the Azure portal cannot manage services in the Azure classic portal.

In order for your new user to get into the classic Azure portal, they need to have service admin or co-admin access to an Azure subscription. You can do one of the following:

- Add the new user as a co-admin to your existing subscription (you would do this in the classic portal)
- [Make the new user the service admin](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/#how-to-change-service-administrator-for-a-subscription) for the subscription
- [Transfer the entire subscription to the new user](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-subscription-transfer/) (which also makes the new user the account admin)

Comment: Philippe, i tried the first option and now I'm able to get into the classic site.
thanks very much