# How to check if Azure Classic Subscription exist in my account

Tags: azure

There is a classic Network Security Group resource in one of my subscriptions, yet when I open manage.windowsazure.com I get redirected to normal Portal. According to this [No subscriptions found in the old Azure portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149785/no-subscriptions-found-in-the-old-azure-portal) that means that I have no classic Azure subscriptions. Can a classic resource exist without classic subscription?
I have global administrator Azure AD role, I'm Co-administrator for all of the Subscriptions listed in the Portal. When I run a PowerShell command `Add-AzureAccount` 
I get:

```
No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure Service Management (RDFE). This means that the logged in user is not an administrator or co-administrator for any 
account.\r\nDid you mean to execute Connect-AzureRmAccount?
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "classic subscription." Rather, your subscription may have classic *services*. And if you do a search (in the portal) across "All Services" and search for "network security" - you'll see a choice for "Network security groups (classic)"

Comment: If so, why this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/classic-administrators
Mentions "classic subscription administrator role"? And why can't I access Classic portal?

Comment: The "classic portal" has been gone for years. There's just one portal that shows all resources (both Classic and Resource Manager). As for credentials, that's primarily for using the REST API / PowerShell, cli, where you have to authenticate against your credentials using the "classic" version of the APIs. Just go into the portal, logged in with your normal credentials, and look through the various "classic" resources (storage, network security groups, vm's, etc)

Comment: Thank you! I would accept this comment as an answer.

Comment: So, I can edit the classic resource from Portal, but not from PowerShell? How come the PowerShell says that I'm not co-administrator when I am? Also, regarding the Classic portal I was confused because I actually used to be able to access both new and classic portal from other accounts.

Comment: I went ahead and posted as an answer. Probably better than comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... There's no such thing as a "classic subscription." Rather, your subscription may have "classic" services. And if you do a search (in the portal) across "All Services" and search for "network security" - you'll see a choice for "Network security groups (classic)":

[image: Network Security Groups (classic)]

As for credentials: there's only one portal now (`portal.azure.com`) - the old ("classic") portal is no more. Your current credentials let you navigate both "Classic" and "Resource Manager" resources.

There are two sets of PowerShell cmdlets, one set for dealing with "Classic" resources and one set for "Resource Manager resources. Underneath are different API calls, so you need to switch between the types.

Comment: How can I change between the types?

Comment: Sorry - originally there used to be a mode-switch cmdlet. Now it's just specifically-named cmdlets, so you need to switch between which ones you use - no longer an actual mode-switch. You'd need to look up the various ones ( about to board a flight and can't do that at the moment).

Comment: come on, years ;) i dont think even a year passed ;)